# Bootstrap confirmation requires two clicks before shows up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-confirmation

```js
var myJSON = {
  "customers": [{
      "id": 100,
      "first": "Mike",
      "last": "Johnson",
      "email": "mjohnson@gmail.com",
      "position": "Consultant"
    },
    {
      "id": 101,
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Dunn",
      "email": "jdunn@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 109,
      "first": "Lisa",
      "last": "Morgan",
      "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
      "position": "Secretary"
    },
    {
      "id": 233,
      "first": "Kris",
      "last": "Bradley",
      "email": "kbradley@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 57,
      "first": "Dave",
      "last": "Hart",
      "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
      "position": "Supervisor"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  generateTbl();
});

function generateTbl() {
  var jsonData = myJSON.customers,
    buildTbl = "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-striped' id='customers'><thead><tr><th>Customer ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Position</th><th>Delete</th></thead><tbody>";

  for (var key in jsonData) {
    buildTbl += "<tr id='row_" + jsonData[key].id + "'><td data-id='id'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].id) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='first'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].first) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='last'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].last) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='email'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].email) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='position'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].position) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm customer_delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
  }
  buildTbl += "</tbody></table></div>";
  $('#customers_data').empty().append(buildTbl);
  buildDataTable('customers', [5], 5);
}

function buildDataTable(tblID, columnsArray, displayLength) {
  $('#' + tblID).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': columnsArray
    }]
  });
}

$('#customers_data').on('click', '#customers :button.customer_delete', deleteCustomer);

function deleteCustomer() {
  var recordID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), // Get record ID.
    targetTr = $(this).parents('tr');

  $(this).confirmation({
    rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
    placement: 'bottom',
    singleton: true,
    title: 'Do you want to remove this account?',
    onConfirm: function() {
      if (recordID) {
        var table = $('#customers').DataTable(); // Select DataTable by ID.
        table.row(targetTr).remove().draw(); // Remove record from DataTable.
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Hearing Application</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.7/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- *** Start: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
  <!-- *** End: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Welcome to Main Page</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="customers_data" class="table-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in my example first time you click on delete button dialog is not showing. Second time will show. What could be the reason why dialog is not showing on the first click? I'm not sure if that has to do anything with dynamically built table? If anyone knows solution for this please let me know.

Comment: Which confirmation plugin are you using?  It sounds like the call to `confirmation()` is performing the initialization, not opening automatically.  You may need to look at the api for the plugin and find if there is a logical way to open the confirmation after the initialization

Comment: @Taplar Version it's right in the example. I believe it's 1.0.7.

Comment: If it is this plugin, http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/, then you should be able to do `$(this).confirmation('show');` after you initialize it.  You can find details about it under the Methods on that page.

Comment: @Taplar Do you know `cdn` from that source for confirmation?

Comment: I assumed it was that plugin as your rootSelector key and value match the examples on that site

Comment: I copied your snippet to an answer and added that command and it does fix your issue.

Comment: @Taplar I just tried and still requires two clicks in my example above.

Answer (score 3):

You should be creating your confirmation before the button click, but if you must do it this way add in a `$(this).confirmation('show')` after you create the confirmation.. This piece of code makes it work:

```js
var myJSON = {
  "customers": [{
      "id": 100,
      "first": "Mike",
      "last": "Johnson",
      "email": "mjohnson@gmail.com",
      "position": "Consultant"
    },
    {
      "id": 101,
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Dunn",
      "email": "jdunn@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 109,
      "first": "Lisa",
      "last": "Morgan",
      "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
      "position": "Secretary"
    },
    {
      "id": 233,
      "first": "Kris",
      "last": "Bradley",
      "email": "kbradley@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 57,
      "first": "Dave",
      "last": "Hart",
      "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
      "position": "Supervisor"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  generateTbl();
});

function generateTbl() {
  var jsonData = myJSON.customers,
    buildTbl = "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-striped' id='customers'><thead><tr><th>Customer ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Position</th><th>Delete</th></thead><tbody>";

  for (var key in jsonData) {
    buildTbl += "<tr id='row_" + jsonData[key].id + "'><td data-id='id'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].id) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='first'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].first) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='last'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].last) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='email'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].email) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='position'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].position) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm customer_delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
  }
  buildTbl += "</tbody></table></div>";
  $('#customers_data').empty().append(buildTbl);
  buildDataTable('customers', [5], 5);
}

function buildDataTable(tblID, columnsArray, displayLength) {
  $('#' + tblID).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': columnsArray
    }]
  });
}

$('#customers_data').on('click', ':button.customer_delete', deleteCustomer);

function deleteCustomer() {
  var recordID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), // Get record ID.
    targetTr = $(this).parents('tr');
    

  $(this).confirmation({
    rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
    placement: 'bottom',
    singleton: true,
    title: 'Do you want to remove this account?',
    onConfirm: function() {
      if (recordID) {
        var table = $('#customers').DataTable(); // Select DataTable by ID.
        table.row(targetTr).remove().draw(); // Remove record from DataTable.
      }
    }
  });
  $(this).confirmation('show');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Hearing Application</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.7/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- *** Start: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
  <!-- *** End: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Welcome to Main Page</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="customers_data" class="table-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to create confirmation before I do on click? I think that actually will prevent some of the problems that I have.

Answer (score 2):

Added the line to the code to show it does show the confirmation on the first click.

```js
var myJSON = {
  "customers": [{
      "id": 100,
      "first": "Mike",
      "last": "Johnson",
      "email": "mjohnson@gmail.com",
      "position": "Consultant"
    },
    {
      "id": 101,
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Dunn",
      "email": "jdunn@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 109,
      "first": "Lisa",
      "last": "Morgan",
      "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
      "position": "Secretary"
    },
    {
      "id": 233,
      "first": "Kris",
      "last": "Bradley",
      "email": "kbradley@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 57,
      "first": "Dave",
      "last": "Hart",
      "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
      "position": "Supervisor"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  generateTbl();
});

function generateTbl() {
  var jsonData = myJSON.customers,
    buildTbl = "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-striped' id='customers'><thead><tr><th>Customer ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Position</th><th>Delete</th></thead><tbody>";

  for (var key in jsonData) {
    buildTbl += "<tr id='row_" + jsonData[key].id + "'><td data-id='id'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].id) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='first'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].first) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='last'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].last) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='email'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].email) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='position'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].position) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm customer_delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
  }
  buildTbl += "</tbody></table></div>";
  $('#customers_data').empty().append(buildTbl);
  buildDataTable('customers', [5], 5);
}

function buildDataTable(tblID, columnsArray, displayLength) {
  $('#' + tblID).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': columnsArray
    }]
  });
}

$('#customers_data').on('click', '#customers :button.customer_delete', deleteCustomer);

function deleteCustomer() {
  var recordID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), // Get record ID.
    targetTr = $(this).parents('tr');

  $(this).confirmation({
    rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
    placement: 'bottom',
    singleton: true,
    title: 'Do you want to remove this account?',
    onConfirm: function() {
      if (recordID) {
        var table = $('#customers').DataTable(); // Select DataTable by ID.
        table.row(targetTr).remove().draw(); // Remove record from DataTable.
      }
    }
  });
  
  //added this line to show the confirmation immediately after initialization
  $(this).confirmation('show');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Hearing Application</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.7/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- *** Start: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
  <!-- *** End: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Welcome to Main Page</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="customers_data" class="table-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```